# Unable to fix CORS issue with Spring Boot and Angular

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot, cors

I am new to Spring Boot and Angular and struggling with the CORS issue.

I want to implement a global CORS filter and tried implementing CorsFilter, WebMvcConfigurer and also tried with WebMvcConfigurerAdapter class but none of the methods seem to be working. I know I'm missing something but can't figure out what. If someone could please find a solution in my code, it would be great help.

I also have implemented Basic Auth and added that code if that's any help.

Here's my code.

**Angular API Call**

**api.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  userLogin(username: String, password: String) {
    let postBody = {
      "username" : username,
      "password" : password
    };
    let httpOptions = {
      headers : new HttpHeaders({
        "Content-Type" : "application/json",
        "Authorization" : "Basic " + btoa('myUsername:myPassword')
      })
    }
    return this.httpClient.post("http://localhost:8080/userLogin", postBody, httpOptions);
  }

}
```

Here's my API code.

**MainApp.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String... str) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApp.class, str);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(MainApp.class);
    }

}
```

**Config.java**

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("POST"));
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }
}
```

**NotebookController.java**

```
@RestController
public class NotebookController {

    @Autowired
    IUsersRepo usersRepo;
    @Autowired
    INotesRepo notesRepo;

    @PostMapping("userLogin")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<String> userLogin(@RequestParam("username") String username, @RequestParam("password") String password) {
        ObjectWriter objectWriter = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
        List<Users> usersList = usersRepo.findByUsernameEqualsAndPasswordEquals(username, password);
        boolean userVerified = usersList.size() > 0 ? true : false;
        HashMap<String, Boolean> outputMap = new HashMap<>();
        outputMap.put("authenticated", userVerified);
        String outputJson = "";
        try {
            outputJson = objectWriter.writeValueAsString(outputMap);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        outputJson = outputJson.toString();
        ResponseEntity<String> response = new ResponseEntity<String>(outputJson, HttpStatus.OK);
        return response;
    }
}
```

**Authentication.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class Authentication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationEntryPoint authEntryPoint;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable();

        //Authorise all incoming requests
        http.authorizeRequests().and().httpBasic();
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();

        //Use AuthenticationEntryPoint to authorise username/password
        http.httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint);
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("POST"));
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder getEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        String username = "myUsername";
        String password = "myPassword";

        InMemoryUserDetailsManagerConfigurer<AuthenticationManagerBuilder> mngConfig = authenticationManagerBuilder.inMemoryAuthentication();

        mngConfig.withUser(username).password(password).roles("USER");
    }

}
```

**AuthEntryPoint.java**

```
@Component
public class AuthEntryPoint extends BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        super.commence(request, response, authException);
        response.addHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=" + getRealmName());
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        writer.println("HTTP Status 401: Unauthorised | " + authException.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        setRealmName("Online Notebook");
        super.afterPropertiesSet();
    }

}
```

Please see the browser console as well.

https://imgur.com/a/hHceJDw

Comment: The error message show in the image at https://imgur.com/a/hHceJDw says, *“request header field "authorization" is not allowed by access-control-allow-headers in preflight response”*. So you need to change your code to have `configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization", "Content-Type"))`. And please never post screenshots of error messages into questions at Stack Overflow. Always copy and paste in the error messages as text.

Comment: @sideshowbarker Thanks a lot for the help. It worked. And I'll also take your advice into consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using spring security , you could configure cors along with spring security like below so that the pre-flight check request goes through spring security.

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and()
            //other configurations that you want
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource()
    {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        //or any domain that you want to restrict to 
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept","Authorization"));
   configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST"));
        //Add the method support as you like 
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new     UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```

The issue that you might be facing is that spring security is not letting through the pre-flight checkup requests and failing them. For more analysis , please share your browser logs or errors from the request .

From the browser error it can be seen that the header `"Authorization"` that you have added to the request is not allowed by the cors configuration as you have specified only the headers `"Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept"` in your cors configuration. Add the `"Authorization"` header as well to cors configuration and the issue should be fixed.

Comment: I tried as you suggested but I'm still getting the same error. I have updated the Authentication.java file as suggested and updated it in the question as well. I also added the browser output at the end.

Comment: I also tried removing the csrf security but that didn't work as well.

Comment: @ChiranjeevJain Add the authorization header to `configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept"));` , it will resolve your issue